# How to change an atrribute in tag div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had the problem when I want to replace attribute img. 
In `class="HotProject_item HotProject_item_preview isotope-item"` content class ="content-asset" have 
`<img src="/Uploads/images/0110/112/image012.jpg"` .

I want to change img src with new image. Can you help me?

```
<div class="HotProject_item HotProject_item_preview isotope-item" zorder="1" row-num="1" data-id="149" 
enddate="31/12/2014" mark="10" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"> 
<div class="content content_1 work" data-id="149" orgclass="content_1" curclass="content_1"> 
<div class="content-tl"> 
<div class="content-tr">
</div> 
</div> <div class="content-bl"> <div class="content-br"> <div class="content-main"> 
<div class="content-mask-tl"></div> <div class="content-mask-tr"></div> <div class="content-mask-bl"></div> <div class="content-mask-br">
</div> <div class="content-inner"> 
<div class="content-top"> 
<div class="content-asset"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="149"> <img src="/Uploads/images/B%C3%ACnh%20ch%E1%BB%8Dn%20sp/thang%207/tu-lanh-1.jpg" alt=""> </a> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="content-info"> <p class="title"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="149">Title ABC</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="expand"> <img src="../HotProject/Css/img/more.png"> </a> </p> 
<div class="divider"><span></span></div> 
<div class="subtitle summary" style="visibility: visible;">

  Decription :)


 &nbsp;
 </div> 
 <div class="subtitle description" style="visibility: visible;">

  Subtitle


 &nbsp;</div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="content_detail">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so

```
$(".content-asset img").attr("src","newimg.jpg");
```

It means , Change its source attribute to point to newimg.jpg

Comment: Thank you. In Code have multi class content-asset. But only one class="HotProject_item HotProject_item_preview isotope-item" . If I use this code, Multi class have name content-asset can together to change.

Comment: @GiangDHN ,then wat you want to change?Where should the change be reflected?

Comment: @GiangDHN , Welcome , You can do +1 and accept as Answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Oke, thank you a lot. I have done.